# Modalverben zu + Infinitiv + sein

Tags: modal-verb, infinitive, passive

Ich habe einen Satz gelesen und der lautet:

> Später sollte dieser Satz auf den Plakaten der Nationalsozialisten zu lesen sein.

Meine Fragen sind:

1. Hat "sollte" hier sinngemäß eine subjektive Bedeutung? Wenn es so ist, heißt es "etwas vom Dritten gehört", aber das hier klingt nicht so. Warum?
2. Ist "zu lesen sein" eine passiv Ersatzform? Wenn ja, warum wurde dieser Satz nicht als "sollte... gelesen werden" geschrieben?

Comment: Der Fachbegriff für diese Verwendung scheint tatsächlich "subjektive Bedeutung" zu sein. Hier ist ein Dokument der Universität München: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=16&ved=2ahUKEwiJzsH1sL7aAhUR6qQKHYoCBKMQFjAPegUIABCkAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dietz-und-daf.de%2FGD_DkfA%2FGramminfo%2Ftxt_MII2%2FMV%2520-%2520Uebersicht.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1YuVnsVXlSIcIn84AQxxEf

Answer (score 5):

## Zur ersten Frage: "sollte ... sein"

Die Konstruktion '***sollen (Präteritum) + Infinitiv***' als vorausschauende Vorschau von einem vergangenen Zeitpunkt aus in einer Erzählung wird in der Duden-Grammatik von 2006 mit dem "*Schicksalsfutur*" (würde + Infinitiv) verglichen. In der Duden-Grammatik wird unterschieden:

- "**historisches Futur**" auf Basis des historischen Präsens:

> Im Jahr 1723 nimmt Bach seine Tätigkeit als Thomaskantor in Leipzig auf. Dort wird er bis zu seinem Tode bleiben.

- "**Schicksalsfutur**" mit '*würde + Infinitiv*' bei Erzähltexten im Präteritum:

> Im Jahr 1723 nahm Bach seine Tätigkeit als Thomaskantor in Leipzig auf. Dort würde er bis zu seinem Tode bleiben.

- Dieses "Schicksalsfutur" kann auch durch durch 'sollte + Infinitiv'
  wiedergegeben werden:

> Im Jahr 1723 nahm Bach seine Tätigkeit als Thomaskantor in Leipzig auf. Dort sollte er bis zu seinem Tode bleiben.

Diese Funktion von 'sollen' entspricht vereinfacht gesagt dem Bedeutungsanteil von 'sollen', dass jemand oder etwas anderes als der Äußernde und der Rezipient will, dass etwas geschieht:

> Du sollst sofort zu Hause anrufen.

= indirekte Aufforderung: Jemand anderes, der in dem Satz nicht benannt wird, will das und fordert dich dazu auf.

> Su sollst nicht töten.

= allgemeine Norm: Die moralische Norm oder ein Gesetz will das und verlangt das von dir.

> Er sollte damit letztendlich recht behalten.

= "Schicksal": Der tatsächliche Gang der Ereignisse war so, dass die hier im Vorgriff genannte Tatsache sich später so bewahrheitete. Diese Interpretation wird gelegentlich als "das Schicksal wollte, dass ..." formuliert: *Das Schicksal wollte, dass unsere Wege sich nach 20 Jahren wieder kreuzten*.

*) In diesem Sinne nachzulesen in der Duden-Grammatik 2006 auf den Seiten 564 f. Rz 820, S. 518 Rz 739, S. 515 Rz 731.

Die Deutschlehrerseite *deutschplus.net* nennt diese *sollte*-Konstruktion "*Zukunft in der Vergangenheit*" (https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Modalverb_sollen/Modalverb-sollen-Zukunft-in-der-Vergangenheit).

Der Duden erwähnt an späterer Stelle, dass die sollte-Konstruktion mit dem Präteritum konkurriert (S. 1124 Rz 1842). Statt

> Um einer Hinrichtung zu entgehen, war Galileo Galilei gezwungen, seine Überlegungen zum Heliozentrismus zu widerrufen. Diese würden / sollten sich später jedoch als zutreffend herausstellen.

kann man auch formulieren:

> Um einer Hinrichtung zu entgehen, war er gezwungen, seine Überlegungen zum Heliozentrismus zu widerrufen. Diese stellten sich später jedoch als zutreffend heraus.

Der Unterschied ist, dass der Satz im "Schicksalsfutur" eine Erzählperspektive Zeigt (= es 'spricht' der Erzähler), die beim reinen Präteritum fehlt.

Answer (score 3):

Der gesamte Artikel befasst sich mit einer Begebenheit in der Vergangenheit. Das sollte bezieht sich dabei auf eine Tatsache, die aber zu dem Zeitpunkt noch nicht bekannt ist.

In diesem speziellen Fall nimmt *sollte* die Funktion des Futur 1 ein, und könnte genausogut durch "wird" ersetzt werden. Dadurch wird der Satz aber mehrdeutig, und das *sollte* drückt aus, dass es sich eben nicht um die tatsächliche Zukunft (aus Sicht des Lesers), sondern nur um die Zukunft aus Sicht der damaligen Zeit handelt.

Leider finde ich den grammatikalischen Fachbegriff hierfür nicht, und kann es deshalb nur Laienhaft beschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

## Zur zweiten Frage: "*zu + Infinitiv + sein*"

Es gibt keine einheitliche Antwort auf die Frage, was das Passiv gegenüber dem Aktiv ist. Eine wesentliche Leistung von Passiv-Konstruktionen ist es, dass ein Agens, dass im Aktivsatz obligatorisch ist und dort als Subjekt auftritt, im Passivsatz fehlen kann:

> 'Man' hat das Haus abgerissen > Das Haus wurde abgerissen.

Von wem, ist im Passivsatz unerheblich.

Man spricht üblicherweise bei einer "*werden + Partizip II*"-Konstruktion dann von einem Passiv, wenn ein komplementärer Aktivsatz gebildet werden kann, bei dem das Subjekt des Passivsatzes zum Akkusativobjekt (oder beim *bekommen*-Passiv zum Dativobjekt) des korrespondierenden Aktivsatzes wird.

> *das Buch* wurde 2011 herausgebracht = der Verlag brachte *das Buch* 2011
> heraus
>
> *sie* bekam Blumen geschenkt = jemand schenkte *ihr* Blumen

Ein *werden*-Passivsatz kann in einen resultativen *sein*-Passivsatz überführt werden:

> Das Haus ist (jetzt) abgerissen.

Sowohl *werden*- als auch *sein*-Passiv werden mit dem Partizip Perfekt konstruiert.

Die Struktur "*zu + Infinitiv + sein*" hat zusätzlich zum 'passivischen' einen modalen Bedeutungsanteil, der aber nicht auf '*müssen/sollen*' (negativ: *nicht müssen/sollen/brauchen*) oder auf '*(nicht) können/dürfen*' festgelegt werden kann, sondern je nach Zusammenhang variabel zu verstehen ist:

> die Fenster sind zu schließen > müssen/sollen geschlossen werden
>
> die Aufgabe ist leicht zu lösen > kann leicht gelöst werden

Der Satz

> später sollte dieser Satz auf den Plakaten der Nationalsozialisten gelesen werden

hätte die Bedeutung: *Er wurde tatsächlich gelesen*. Hingegen hat der Satz

> später sollte dieser Satz auf den Plakaten der Nationalsozialisten zu lesen sein

die Bedeutung: *der Satz konnte (später so) gelesen werden* (bzw.: *er war dort wiederzufinden*). Ob er tatsächlich gelesen wurde, wird nicht ausgesagt.

Man kann die Verbverbindung '*irgendwo zu lesen sein*' als lexikalische Einheit mit der Bedeutung 'irgendwo geschrieben stehen' auffassen; sie ähnelt der Kombination '*irgendwo zu finden sein*'. Ähnliche Verbindungen sind:

> das ist nicht zu schaffen > das kann (in dieser Zeit) nicht geschafft werden
>
> das ist nicht zu akzeptieren > das kann nicht akzeptiert werden

Manchmal passt aus semantischen und/oder stilistischen Gründen eher ein 'man'-Satz:

> das ist nicht zu glauben > das kann man nicht / kann kein Mensch glauben
>
> das ist nicht zu verstehen > das kann man nicht verstehen
>
> da ist nichts zu sehen > da kann man nichts sehen

Die Duden-Grammatik von 2006 ordnet auf S. 568 Rz 827 diesen Gebrauch des Verbs *sein* den Modalitätsverben zu und bezieht dort auch die '*haben + zu + Infinitiv*'-Konstruktion mit dem Modalitätsverb '*haben*' ein:

> du hast das nicht zu kritisieren > das darf (von dir) nicht kritisiert werden.

Mit '*sein*' (und '*stehen*', '*bleiben*' ...) gibt es weitere derartige lexikalisierte Verbindungen (*zu befürchten sein/stehen, zu erwarten sein/stehen, zu hoffen sein/bleiben* ...).

### Fazit

Der Satz ist nach allem, was gesagt wurde, zu verstehen als:

> Jahre später / In einer späteren Zeit würde man diesen Satz wieder auf Plakaten der Nationalsozialisten lesen können.

Gut möglich, dass der Autor hier einen geistigen Vorläufer des Nationalsozialismus brandmarken will. Dieses Argumentationsschema ist nicht nur in Deutschland gleichzusetzen mit einer ultimativen (kaum noch steigerbaren) Kritik.