# How to better identify Future-in-the-Past of sollte? (Prediction)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, modal-verb

How to better identify Future-in-the-Past of *sollte* (prediction) by the speaker? It is said that *sollte* is different from *würden* in that it is a prediction by the speaker.

For example:

> Er ist nach New York umgezogen und er *sollte* nie wieder in Hamburg wohnen.
>
> <sub>(He moved to New York and he would never again live in Hamburg.)</sub>

Where to find plenty of examples of this usage of *sollte*? Any ideas how *sollte* became to be used in this sense of prediction?

Idea for this post came from Hammer’s German Grammar and Usage six edition , page 382.

To be clear the example sentence was not in Hammer but was created by myself.

Comment: The English version is ambiguous; two possible interpretations: "He moved to New York and he was never again to live in Hamburg." ("would" = possibility) "He moved to New York and refused  to live in Hamburg ever again ." ("would" = willingness) I'm sure you meant the first interpretation, but you have to be careful with the phrasing to avoid translating the wrong version into German, especially when using machine translation.

Comment: @RDBury The English version is no more ambiguous than the German version. It's obvious in each case which sense of *sollen/would* is intended.

Comment: @PiedPiper: Yes, the German version seemed ambiguous to me as well, but that information would be included in an answer. In other words, I don't mind if the German example is ambiguous, that's part of the question and should be part of the answer. But if you're going to explain what you think it means in English then you should be precise.

Comment: The German sentence seems off to me. Where is it from?

Comment: Sentence was created by me as a way of an example. Perhaps not the best example but the point of the exercise was to get a better feel and understanding of the way in which sollte is used in this future-in-the-past (prediction) sense. Feel free to amend.

Comment: The German sentence looks totally fine to me. Granted, this type of construction is not common (anymore) in every day German, but rather has an air of style and elevated and precise command of German language use to it.

Comment: @planetmaker which is why I would expect preterite in the first part.

Comment: Perhaps I should not  have wrote the first part "Er ist nach New York umgezogen und " ?

Comment: I think @Carsten means the first part should read like "Er *war* nach New York umgezogen...". Yet I don't see the necessity for that. Present tense can be used, too. Choice of tense depends on context.

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/a/43553/35111.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking of the completely wrong meaning here, so real examples would help. I was reading the "sollte" part as something told to us by an omniscient narrator, and that did not fit stylistically with the use of Perfekt (I did not analyse it as Präsenz) in the first sentence.

Comment: Compare with the example of "Schicksalsfutur" in the answer linked by @DavidVogt.

Comment: @RDBury: Please stop posting answers in comments! The idea of stackexchange is not about discussing half-baked ideas in comments. You can do this in the chat if you want. Stackexchange was created as a platform where questions will be answered in dedicated answer-postings. Please do not abuse comments for  answers and discussions. See https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487 and https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment (items "Answering a question" and "Secondary discussion")

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: I didn't answer the question or even give a hint. I have no idea what you're talking about here. Sometimes a question is unclear or requires further information; I assume it's allowed to comment on that.

Comment: I agree with Carsten, it should be "Er ist n HH umgezogen und soll nie wieder zurück", bzw. selbiges in Praeteritum. Natürlich kann man "sollte" auch im Praes. gesetzt, das klingt dann aber off und bedarf einer Kennzeichnung, "sollte besser/lieber" für pos./neg. Konnotation, ähnlich wie En. "We had better", "I would rather", was eigentlich "wollen" bedeutet. Kommentarntwort weil sonst mein Draft unter einer anderen Frage flötieren geht und es ja eigentlich gar keine Antwort nach Treu und Glauben darstellen soll. *Teh!* - wie ein Kollege in Ablehnung auszurufen pflegte (etwa En. "tsk")

Comment: What is your exact question? There are three of them in your post:
1. How to better identify Future-in-the-Past of sollte (prediction) by the speaker?
2. Where to find plenty of examples of this usage of sollte? 
3. Any ideas how sollte became to be used in this sense of prediction?

Comment: That's a reasonable demand to satisfy 1 and 2 in order to prove 3, because the development does probably alternate between speaker's views on 1 and 2. Hence, depending on which order is meaningful, showing the first step would be the most bening interpretation. As New German literature reaches a few centuries, a chronological Einortnung of the usage would already warrant the etymology tag.

Answer (score 4):

> How to better identify Future-in-the-Past of sollte (prediction) by the speaker?

The example you give is not a *prediction* at all. Its posture is looking back from some future. Your example:

> Er ist nach New York umgezogen und er sollte nie wieder in Hamburg wohnen.

*Probably* means: you relate a story about someone. He moved to New York and, back then when he moved, that was maybe only meant for a short time. But now, looking back, you notice that he never moved back. The sentence also implies that he won't ever go back - most probably because he is dead.

For this - relating a story - the *Praeteritum* is used in German, like its cousin *preterite* is used in English. Your sentence is in *Perfekt* (the analogue in English would be *present perfect*) and this is probably what most native speakers found "off". *If* my interpretation of your example sentence is correct it should be rephrased this way:

*Er zog nach New York um und er sollte nie wieder in Hamburg wohnen.*

Your translation is - if what i said about the meaning of the example sentence before was correct - back to English is also not flawless, as @RDBury in his comment pointed out. A better translation (always supposing my interpretation of your example was correct) would be:

*He moved to New York and never was to live in Hamburg again.*

Examples for this use of "sollte" can be found all over German literature because it is a common colloquial device. The probably most common form is the proverbial:

*Es hat nicht sollen sein.*
or, more modern: *Es sollte nicht sein.*
<sub>It wasn't meant to be.</sub>

Usually sighed after a plan (or desired outcome of whatever) *almost* succeeded (resp. came to fruition) but finally failed (to happen). i.e. "Fast hätte ich gewonnen, aber es hat nicht sollen sein." <sub>I almost won but it wasn't meant to be.</sub>

Comment: Hammer’s GERMAN Grammar and Usage sixth edition Martin Durrell  uses this example , page 382   "Er sollte niemals nach Deutschland zurückkehren" translation given "He would never return to Germany"  which is a prediction by the speaker.

Comment: Perhaps , my example did not work well in this "prediction"  by the speaker sense. But to better understand this use of "sollte" as a "prediction" in the past was the orginal idea of the post.